# Error in starting asynctask in android

Tags: java, android

I am starting two asynchronous task in two diffrent services first one works correctly and opens a socket but second one is not starting here is the code my application is based on client socket  programing in wifip2p.

```
    public class RecieveAudioService extends Service {

    String tag = "Recieve Audio Service";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recieve audio :requesting to client", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String[] param = {"h", "j", "k"};

        new request().execute();
        Log.v("Recieve Audio", "Inside Recieve audio service");

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

//===================== This class is sending request to server for connection when invocked
    public class request extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            Log.v("second asyn", "this is second asynchronous task");

            try {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request to connect sent to server",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String toConnectDeviceIP = "192.168.49.1";
                Integer toConnectDevicePort = 8988;

                Socket connect = new Socket();

                connect.bind(null);
                connect.connect((new InetSocketAddress(toConnectDeviceIP, toConnectDevicePort)),
                        5000);
                Log.v(tag, "sent the connection request to clint");
                connect.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.v(tag, "" + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "i found exception in connection"
                        +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return "success";
        }
    }
//====================================================================

}
```

Comment: You can only run a single instance of a async task at a time.

Comment: Then how can i send request to server if i do it in activity it gives error networkOperationOnMainThread or something like this.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example

Comment: you need a second executor for your other asynctask. or just use a thread, since apparently you are not doing anything with the result. or even a IntentService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you launch your app on Android 4.x/3.x. Before Android 3.0 `AsyncTasks` ran concurrently but later versions(>3.x) of system executes tasks one after another. So you have two choices:

a) Use `Threads` instead of `AsyncTasks`

b) Use `executeOnExecutor` of `AsyncTask` to execute tasks concurrently:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it seems helpful . . :)